# Determining highway direction in here maps

Tags: ios, here-api, here-maps-rest

Does Here map iOS sdk provides Highway direction?

Example: While driving on US Highways/Interstate, Here map is providing information like I-5 or WA-14.
Can we get which highway/interstate direction we are heading into. Like I-5 N or WA-14 S.

Comment: Maybe you can check out https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/dev_guide/topics/routing.html 
This contains information on how to specify routing

Answer (score 1):

You can allways use *course* infromation taken from *currentPosition*(NMAGeoPositon object) of the NMAPositionManager.

Swift

```
NMAPositionManager.sharedInstance().currentPosition?.course
```

or Objective-C

```
[NMAPositionManager sharedPositioningManager].currentPosition.course
```

Valid course values are in the range [0, 360), with 0 degrees representing north and values increasing clockwise. Thus, east is 90 degrees, south is 180 degrees, and so on. Will be NMAGeoPositionUnknownValue if unknown.

---

Also it can be obtained from waypoint course.

```
calculatedRoute.waypoints[idx].course;
```

or aliases 'start', 'destination' can be used

```
calculatedRoute.start.course;
calculatedRoute.destination.course;
```

---

Another one is to use mapOrientation of maneuver

```
calculatedRoute.maneuvers[idx].mapOrientation
```

The angle (from north) at the start of the maneuver, in degrees. Zero represents true-north, with increasing values representing a clockwise progression of map orientation.